# Adding a string to the end of the URL after clicking on a button

Tags: reactjs

In the bellow App, I want to add the user's first-name to the end of the page url in the address bar after clicking of the **Details** button and again want to remove it after clicking on the **Back to the list** button.

I googled a lot but still don't understand how can I add this feature.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***App.js***

```
import UserList from './List'

const App = props => {
  const [id, newID] = useState(null)
  return (
    <>
      <UserList id={id} setID={newID} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

***List.js***

```
const UserList = ({ id, setID }) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([])

  const fetchResource = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.randomuser.me'
    )
    setResources(response.data.results)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResource()
  }, [])

  const renderItem = (item, newID) => {

    return (
      <Fragment key={item.login.uuid}>
        {newID ? (
          // User view
          <div key={item.login.uuid}>
            <div>
              <h2>
                {item.name.first} {item.name.last}
              </h2>
              <p>
                {item.phone}
                <br />
                {item.email}
              </p>
              <button onClick={() => setID(null)}>
                Back to the list
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          // List view
          <li key={item.login.uuid}>
            <div>
              <h2>
                {item.name.first} {item.name.last}
              </h2>
              <button onClick={() => setID(item.login.uuid)}>
                Details
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        )}
      <Fragment/>
    )
  }

  const user = resources.find(user => user.login.uuid === id)

  if (user) {
    // User view
    return <div>{renderItem(user, true)}</div>
  } else {
    // List view
    return (
      <ul>
        {resources.map(user => renderItem(user, false))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default UserList
```

Comment: url in the address bar of the browser? If so you should use `window.location` that would reload the page to the url you want or `window.history.pushState`

Comment: Is there any way, without a page relaod? I don't want to use the React Route for this specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some pseudo-code. It shows how to get the id in the click handler and to use `window.history.pushState`. You can make the value of the ID the username.

```
const handler (e) =>{
    var id = e.currentTarget.id; 
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url" + id);
    //SETID here.
}
<button id = userId onClick ={handler}>
    Details
</button>
```

Edit
Instead of the `id` you can probably use the `name` attribute. because ids can't be duplicated. also, there should probably be brackets around `userId` like `{userId}`

Comment: Thanks. But now if I click on the Details button it should fire tow actions. Something like this: <button onClick={() => handler(item.login.uuid), () => setID(item.login.uuid)}> But this won't work. What would be the right approach?

Comment: first of all you should stop using anonymous functions like that. It leads to bugs.and they say it's bad practice. I have a `handler` separate. Did you try that? I think you can do `setID()` in the handler easily. Inside the same handler. Don't use anonymous functions.

Comment: I showed where to do the set-id in the edit I just made

Answer (score 1):

You most probably want to use react-router for this.
Check https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params for help.

For your specific use case you can just do

```
window.history.pushState("", "", "/new-urls");
```

Just try this in the browser console to see URL change.

So for your context instead of passing the setId you can pass a function like this

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import UserList from "./List";

const App = props => {
  const [id] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <UserList
        id={id}
        setID={id => window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", id)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This adds the user Id at the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks, but for this specific case I don't want to add the React Route. But I assume that adding something to the end of the page-url requires a page reload, right?

Comment: I've edited the answer above to provide the solution without refreshing the page.

Comment: Wow, this seems to be the answer I am looking for. Thanks, however, I'm struggling to implement it in to my code. When I click on the Details button I set the value of id, but now it needs to fire up also another function to change the URL.

Comment: I've added to answer above. Does this solve your issue or send you in the correct direction at least?